# Why scala pattern matching doesn't support `s"$var"`?

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

Scala code:

```
object Path {
  def unapply(s:String):Some[String] = Some(s)
}

val s = "hello world"

val h = "hello"
s match {
  case Path(s"$h world") => println("Get hello")
  case _ => println("???")
}
```

I tried to use `s"$var"` in pattern matching, but it can't compiled:

```
 <console> error: method s is not a case class, nor does it have 
 an unapply/unapplySeq member
            case Path(s"$h world") => println("Get hello")
```

Why scala can't compile it?

If I put it in `if` clause:

```
s match {
  case Path(p) if p == s"$h world" => println("Get hello")
  case _ => println("???")
}
```

It's working well.

Why scala can't compile it?

Comment: You might be interested in this [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tcQgNEFAVjI&t=41m5s); that's different but does the job.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why scala can't compile it?

It's basically a method call (see http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/nightly/docs/library/index.html#scala.StringContext), and method calls aren't allowed in patterns (and don't generally make sense there).

> If I put it in if clause:
>
> It's working well.

Because `if` takes an expression, not a pattern.

Another thing you could do:

```
val A = s"$h world" // note upper-case

s match {
  case Path(A) => ...
}
```